# use one function to different elements javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in JavaScript and I'm tring to find out how I can use the same function to different elements in JavaScript.

I.e. how to set the id value for `document.getElementById` in the function. I do not know why my code does't work.

JavaScript

```
function onhover(imgx)
{
    var x = imgx;
    document.getElementById('x').style.opacity=0.5;
}
```

HTML

```
<img id="img1" src="img1.jpg" onmouseout="onhover('img1')">
<img id="img2" src="img2.jpg" onmouseout="onhover('img2')">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

premising that all handlers should never be defined inside markup (for the sake of separation between logic and contents) , try this

```
<img id="img1" src="img1.jpg" onmouseout="onhover(this)">
<img id="img2" src="img2.jpg" onmouseout="onhover(this)">

function onhover(img) {
   img.style.opacity=0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a trivial change to your code - remove the single quotes around `x`. When you use single- or double-quotes, you're passing the string "x" rather than the value of the variable `x`.

```
function onhover(imgx)
{
    var x = imgx;
    document.getElementById(x).style.opacity=0.5;
}
```

Though, to be honest, you could just use `imgx` straight away; saving it into `x` is a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @Alnitak Honestly I didn't make the connection that the ID being passed to the function was the ID of the element triggering the function. In that case, `this` would be the better option.

Comment: well, it is, but only if you actually pass it as a parameter (for DOM0 inline handlers).  For proper DOM3 (and jQuery) it's implicit.

Answer (score 0):

I have created codebin for you please check using below link.

http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpcc